# Initializing private member variable vector in a templated class

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, graph, private

I'm currently working on a template graph class that utilizes two vectors to create an adjacency matrix. I can get this to work outside of the template class, but I can't seem to initialize the vectors.

Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace GraphNameSpace
{
  template <class T>
  class Graph
  {
  private:
    vector<int> colOfRow(100);
    vector<vector<int> > matrix(100);
  };
}
```

I receive:

error: expected identifier before numeric constant

error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant

What is the reason that those won't initialize in the template class, and what would a solution to this be?
I know this may not be the most efficient way of doing it, but it's the way I understand best. If you would consider another way to be better, would you provide the way you would go about doing this?

Comment: You need to edit your question and include a [mcve]. Your question fails to meet the requirements for the "complete" and "verifiable" part.

Comment: Hello David.  I had a look through your profile after you deleted a question that I had helped you with.  I notice that you have asked several other questions and accepted no answers.  It's not fair to come here for personal benefit and then give nothing back to the people who help you, or to leave behind something that can help people who come across your question in future.  We are a community, and if you want to be part of it you should contribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with template class. You could use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to initialize member variables:

```
namespace GraphNameSpace
{
  template <class T>
  class Graph
  {
  private:
    vector<int> colOfRow;
    vector<vector<int> > matrix;
  public:
    Graph() : colOfRow(100), matrix(100) {}
  };
}
```

Or [default member initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since c++11):

```
namespace GraphNameSpace
{
  template <class T>
  class Graph
  {
  private:
    vector<int> colOfRow{100};
    vector<vector<int> > matrix{100};
  };
}
```

Comment: Worth editing to beat home the point that the vector cannot be initialized how and where OP is trying to initialize it.